# Message buffer representation in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-representation

Imagine having a box A. In this box every 1 second we add a certain number of messages (3/sec in the example), the information of the message is not relevant to store. The messages have an expiration "date" which corresponds to a certain number of seconds that have passed. **How can I represent this in a compact way in python3?**

An example of what would happen is described below where I use a list of messages in box A, where each message is represented by the time it has been "alive" (this is one of the representations I've thought of, but trying to do better):

```
time = 0:
empty

time = 1: 
[0,0,0]

time = 2: 
[1,1,1,0,0,0]

time = 3:
[2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0]
...
```

The messages will have an expire time corresponding to the instant when they will leave the buffer. For example if the time "alive" is over 5 they would be removed.

The objective is to be able to pass several timesteps with a simple computation and be able to calculate the final buffer without doing it 1 step at a time. (e.g. going from time = 3 to time = 9)

The reason I'm asking this is because it won't be just 1 "box", it will be several boxes and each box will have one of these buffers for every other box. So it needs to be as simple as possible. If any clarification is needed please comment below and I will be glad to clarify the problem.

Comment: What is the issue with the current representation?

Comment: In `time=3` one of the `1` values that was added at `time=2` was removed. Was that intentional? If so, why?

Comment: @Deepstop It wasn't, I edited, thanks.

Comment: @vekerdyb I haven't programmed it completely yet. In my head the problem is that, first, the buffers will be huge and the removing/adding to the buffers will be heavy. Second, since I do not need to store any information about each message, I was thinking it would be possible to group them by the time they were in the network that far. Maybe like saying 5 msgs with time = 4, 10 msgs with time = 5, ... But the "time" has to be easily changed. For example a dictionary with time as key would not work since I would have to change all entries each time there was a variable "time" update.

Comment: It sounds like a premature optimisation issue to me. I suggest you start developing the application, and if you do hit performance issues think again.
We'll be able to help better if you have concrete issues to solve.

Comment: @vekerdyb Maybe. Another part of the problem is having to have too many vectors of that size, for example, if I have 11 boxes, I will have 100 vectors, each can have hundreds of entries. I will try something like this and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer would depend on the overall scale, the variability of the number of buffers in each box, the number of boxes, the number of seconds. With lots of variation object representation might be an advantage, but if things are relatively simple, then lists of lists would be a good start.

If the number of values you store each second is always 3, then you could keep a flat list and just use maxlength * 3 for tossing out the expired values. The following assumes the number of values varies.

```
time = 0:
[]

time = 1: 
[[0,0,0]]

time = 2: 
[[1,1,1],[0,0,0]]

time = 3:
[[2,2,2],[1,1,1],[0,0,0]]
```

To add to the front of the list then truncate list to a maximum length (without causing an error if it is shorter)

```
buffer.insert(0, new_values_list)
del buffer[maxlen:]
```

Finally if you need the list flat again when you use it.

```
import itertools
flat_buffer = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(buffer))
```

As mentioned, you may want to use objects to keep things organized, for example by making box into a class.